# "There is good reason" vs "there is a good reason"

Tags: idioms, indefinite-articles

There was a similar question about the sentence *without reason* compared to *without reasons*.

However here I want to ask you, is it idiomatic (and in which particular parts of the world) to omit the article *a* in front of the word *reason* in *there is good reason*?

I have met this expression multiple times in one scientific book written by an Australian native English speaker.

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reason  Phrases like _with reason_ and _have [good] reason to think_ are perfectly standard English.

Comment: Thank you @KateBunting

Comment: 'There is good reason to believe that ...' (a) is the non-count usage; (b) does not specify whether there are many, several or just one good reason/s, but (c) suggests quite strongly that there is a wealth of supporting arguments, and (d) is more formal than the count alternative. // With 'There is reason to believe that ... '  (a), (b) and (d) hold, but the suggestion is that the theory being proposed is far from being uncontestable.

Answer (score 2):

There is a subtle difference between "there is good reason" and "there is *a* good reason".  The first version treats "reason" as a "mass noun" of sorts, implying that there is a body of logic behind the statement.  The second version asserts that there is a specific reason, like the known existence of a specific type of quark, which provides the foundation for the statement.

Answer (score 1):

In Canada (unsure about US or UK but probably applicable there too), when you want to convey that something is probably true, you can say "there is good reason to believe that..." A lot of people in the media will say this to begin a sentence describing a situation without clearcut information or data. It's similar to "we're leaning toward the idea that..." or "it's likely the case that..." so in this sense it is idiomatic.

Adding "a" makes it less idiomatic since the indefinite article suggests you will follow the statement "There is a good reason for..." with what exactly that good reason is. For instance, "I'm going to talk about cats instead of dogs. There is a good reason for this. I prefer the meow of cats to the bark of dogs."

Answer (score 0):

'There is a good reason' treats reasons as countable, and tells us only that there is at least **one** reason for whatever thesis is under discussion. That wording does not tell us anything as to whether there are more reasons in support of the thesis, and whether there are any reasons against the thesis. The claim that there is one good reason for something is thus compatible with it turning out, upon further investigation, that this one good reason is outweighed by even better reasons against it.

On the other hand, *reason* in 'there is good reason', as already pointed out by Hot Licks, functions as a mass term and refers to the overall body of rational support for the thesis under discussion. *Reason*, used in this way, encompasses whatever countable reasons are relevant to the thesis.

Consequently, it would be confusing if somebody were to say 'there is good reason for this proposal, but we should reject it'. There wouldn't, however, be anything strange about somebody saying 'there is a good reason for this proposal, but we should reject it, because there are many good reasons against it'.